# Searching a table and making calculations based off it in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the KG based off of gallons, or gallons based off of kg, of a liquid. However the liquid does not always have the same Brix value (Brix is the amount of sugar in the liquid, the greater the brix the more dense it is and thus the more kg a gallon would be).

I have two large tables:

One with Brix conversions showing all the necessary variables and their values to plug into an equation in order to make the conversion based on how many Brix the liquid is.

[The Column names and examples of what the values are for 8 and 8.5 Brix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K75ea.png)

The second table has info on the liquid including its weight and gallons, these are the parts I need to calculate. I always have either one or the other, more often how many kg it weighs, I also always have the Brix value.

What I want to do is make a formula in the second table that looks at the cell with the brix value, finds the corresponding row in the first table and then takes the "LBS/Gal in air at 20 C" value of that row, but again it is a different column, and inputs that into the equation and then proceeds to calculate the gallons. I have no problem with the equation part, what I need help with is locating the values I need based off of the brix within the equation so that I don't need to do it manually every time.

I tried using the row and match functions to recreate the name of the cell that I need but I wasn't able to get what I needed because the value that came out was not formatted as a cell reference but rather just a text.

Comment: Please try to isolate your real problem and focus on the specific excel issue you have. Share the input data in [markdown table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format and the expected output. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by having a bit more standardization and making a medium length "if then" statement. However, the issue I was having with the previous method is that I was unable to have the function automatically look up the variables that I needed to enter into the equation based on the first table. Regardless, thank you for your willingness to help.